# Solving mod-rewrite issue after removing index.php in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am using Codeigniter on XAMPP server in Windows. I removed index.php from url using .htaccess and Apache mod_rewrite as below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /mysite/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|css|js)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mysite/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

My folder structure is:

```
htdocs\mysite\index.php
htdocs\mysite\application\...
htdocs\mysite\system\...
htdocs\mysite\js\...
htdocs\mysite\css\...
...
```

I have a controller named "main" that is default controller and another controller named "news" and two functions named "index" and "show" in each. All controller functions use a single view file named "header.php" that looks for two file:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/default.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But what is the problem? Only main/index could access to .js and .css files. main/show, news/index and news/show look for a url like:

```
http://localhost/mysite/news/js/jquery.min.js
http://localhost/mysite/news/css/default.css
```

If I use "../js/jquery.min.js" and "../css/default.css" in header.php the problem will be solved except for main/index. I don't want to use separate header files for main/index and other controllers and functions, because the header is the same in all of them. Is there a solution using Apache mod_rewrite or Codeigniter routing config to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: use full path relative to site

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/mysite/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Option 2: use `base_url()` (must be set in config.php)

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/mysite/';
```

-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() . "js/jquery.min.js"; ?>"></script>
```

This isn't an issue with routing or your `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind do this

```
<script src="<?php echo site_url('js/jquery.min.js'); ?>"></script>
```

Instead of this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() . "js/jquery.min.js"; ?>"></script>
```

And remove the  `type="text/javascript"` it's not required